# Mostrar Pdf del lado del cliente Servlets

Tags: java, servlets

alguien podria ayudarme a ver mi error, estoy intentando que se vea o guarde un pdf en el lado del cliente, soy nuevo en esto de servlets, agradeceria cualquier apoyo, gracias
Este es mi codigo hasta ahora

```
@POST
@Path("reporteComisiones")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void reporteComisiones (Dtorest2 dtorest2) throws DocumentException, FileNotFoundException, ParseException, IOException
{      
        Double TotalPositivo = 0.00;
        Double TotalNegativo = 0.00;
        Double TotalFinal = 0.00;
        Date fecha = new Date();

        SimpleDateFormat formateador = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        List<DtoOutrest2> lista = serComisiones(dtorest2);
        Document document = new Document();
        FileOutputStream FOS = new FileOutputStream("C:\\reportes\\"+dtorest2.persona_id+"-"+formateador.format(fecha)+".pdf");
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, FOS);
        document.open();
        Paragraph titulo = new Paragraph("Reporte Comisiones",FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD,20,Font.BOLD,BaseColor.BLUE));

        titulo.setAlignment(titulo.ALIGN_CENTER);
        document.add(titulo);
        Paragraph Indicefecha = new Paragraph("Del "+ dtorest2.FechaIni + "hasta el "+ dtorest2.FechaFin,FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD,12));
        Indicefecha.setAlignment(Indicefecha.ALIGN_CENTER);
        document.add(Indicefecha);
        document.add(new Paragraph("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"));

        document.close();

        HttpServletResponse response = null;
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:\\reportes\\"+dtorest2.persona_id+"-"+formateador.format(fecha)+".pdf");
        byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(data);

        response.setContentType("application/pdf;");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename="" + dtorest2.persona_id+"-"+formateador.format(fecha)+".pdf";");
        response.setContentLength(data.length);
        javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream servletoutputstream = response.getOutputStream();

        servletoutputstream.write(data);
        servletoutputstream.flush();
        servletoutputstream.close();

    }
```

Comment: Estas confundiendo peras con manzanas un servicio Rest como tu ejemplo no es lo mismo que un servlet https://stackoverflow.com/a/12525812/6686356

Answer (score 0):

Tengo la siguiente implementación, espero le sirva.

```
@Path("/path")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response descargarArchivo() {
  File file = new File("/ruta_archivo_servidor.ext");
    if(file.exists()) {
      ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
      response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + archivo);
      return response.build();
    }else {
      return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build();
    }
}
```